# if this two function $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$ such show that $f(\beta)=\alpha$

Tags: functions

let $f[0,1]\to [0,1]$,and $f(x)$is  increasing funcion(does not mean strictly increasing)   such following two condtion
$$f(x)+f(1-x)=1$$
and 
$$\dfrac{f(x)}{2}=f\left(\dfrac{x}{3}\right)$$
show that:for every irrational number $\alpha\in (0,1)$,  there exist unique number $\beta$ such 
$$f(\beta)=\alpha$$

Comment: I assume you mean "for every irrational number $\alpha$ **in [0,1]**".  Is that correct?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Increasing does not mean strictly increasing here --- $f(1/3)=f(2/3)=1/2$, and in fact it is obvious that $f$ is the Cantor function.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, it follows from the assumptions that $f(\frac{1}{3}) = f(\frac{2}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Now note that because of $\frac{f(x)}{2} = f(\frac{x}{3})$, $f(x)$ is rational if and only if $f(\frac{x}{3})$ is rational. And because of $f(x) + f(1-x) = 1$, $f(x)$ is rational if and only if $f(1-x)$ is rational.

So if you start with a given $x$ and you can transform the $x$ into the interval $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$ in finitely many steps by the above operations (either multiply $x$ by 3 or taking $1-x$), you can conclude that $f(x)$ must be rational.

The set which can be transformed into this interval is exactly the complement of the Cantor set (inside $[0,1]$). (Show it using the fact that an element which is not in the Cantor set has a $1$ in its triadic representation).

So you know that only elements in the Cantor set can take an irrational value. To show that no two elements $x_1$ and $x_2$ (with $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ being irrational) of the Cantor set are mapped to the same value you just have to find an $x$ not in the Cantor set satisfying $x_1 < x < x_2$. Then you know by monotonicity that $f(x_1) \leq f(x) \leq f(x_2)$ and because $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ are irrational and $f(x)$ is rational it holds that $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-(For beginners interested in this subject). Let $x\in[0,1]$ and consider the ternary development of $x$ 
$$x=0.a_1a_2a_3a_4\cdots  =\sum_{k\ge0}\left(\frac{a_k}{3^k}\right);a_k\in\{0,1,2\}\tag{1} $$
As it is known, Cantor's set, noted $\cal C$ here, is formed by all the $x\in[0,1]$ such that any of the $a_k$'s above is equal to $1$, only $ 0 $ and $ 2 $ appear. As user10354138's comment  said, the $f(x)$ in this problem is the Cantor function which admits several equivalent definitions. One of them, the original, is as follow (the given by the O.P. can be seen [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CantorFunction.html) where, however,  there is no other equivalent definition in which the Cantor function is defined as the only fixed point of a contracting operator $T$ in the space of the real continuous functions $f$ over $[0,1]$ normed with the norm of uniform convergence and such that $f (0) = 0$ and $f ( 1) = 1$):

The Cantor function transforms the ternary representation (base $ 3 $) of $ x \in [0,1] $ into a diadic number (base $ 2 $) $y=f(x)$ as follows:

►When $x\in\cal C$, all $2$ appearing in $(1)$ is changed by $1$  and the $0$'s remain unchanged.

► When $x\in [0,1]\setminus\cal C$ the expression in $(1)$ is truncated at the first $1$ appeared and all $2$ before this first $1$ is changed by $1$.

Example 1-The triadic representation of the decimal number $\dfrac{2}{27}+\dfrac{2}{81}=\dfrac{8}{81}=0.\overline{098765432}$ is $0.0022_{(3)}$ which is transformed in the diadic $0.0011_{(2)}$ which correspond to the decimal $\dfrac{3}{16}=0.1875$ i.e. $f(0.\overline{098765432})=0.1875\iff f\left(\dfrac{8}{81}\right)=\dfrac{3}{16}$.

Example 2.-The triadic number $0.20221abcd ...._{(3)}$, regardless of the values of the letters in $ \{0,1,2 \}$  is transformed into the diadic number $0.10111_{(2)}$ which corresponds to the decimal $\dfrac12+\dfrac18+\dfrac{1}{16}+\dfrac{1}{32}=\dfrac{23}{32}$. Thus for all $x\in[0,1]$ having the ternary representation $0.20221abcd ...._{(3)}$ one has $f(x)=\dfrac{23}{32}$.

It is not hard to deduce that if $\alpha$ is irrational and $f(\beta)=\alpha$ then $\beta\in \cal C$ because if  the ternary representation of $\beta$ had a $1$ then its image would be rational (why?). The uniqueness of $\beta$ derives from the fact that $f$ is increasing and that $\beta$ does not belong to the intervals in which $ f (x) $ is constant (in all point of $\cal C $ the function $ f(x) $ is strictly increasing and never returns to the same value $ f (\beta) $ when $ x \gt \beta $).

Very different question would be to explicitly calculate  $\beta$ for an irrational $\alpha$ given. For example for the first known irrational $\sqrt2 $. I see this as needing very intricate calculations perhaps impossible to effect. (Am I wrong?).